# Python 3.8 random.choice not working as expected when making choice from list generated from file

Tags: python, random

I'm using python 3.8. I have 4 plain text files containing sections of text. I want to slice each each file into a list of those sections using * as a delimiter, and generate a single string of text by choosing a random string from each list and concatenating them together in a given order. It works, except that it sometimes generates a blank string from one or more of the files. The output should contain one section  of text from each file, in order of the sectionFiles list in the code and the text files.

```
import os
import random
categories = []
result = ''
sourcePath = "C:\\posthelper\\categories\\positive"
os.chdir(sourcePath)

def generate(result):
  sectionFiles = ['intro.txt', 'body.txt', 'referral.txt', 'closing.txt']

  for item in sectionFiles:
    with open(item) as file:
      sectionString = file.read()
      sectionString = sectionString.replace("\n", "")
      sectionStringList = sectionString.split("*") 
      stringChoice = random.choice(sectionStringList)
      result += stringChoice
  return(result)

print(generate(result))

--intro.txt--

Hi.*
Hello.*
Yo.*
What up?*
How are you?*

--referral.txt--

This is a referral.*
This is also a referral.*
This is a referral too.*
This is the fourth referral.*
This is The last referral.*

--body.txt--

This is a body.*
This is also a body.*
This is a body too.*
This is the fourth body.*
This is The last body.*

--closing.txt--
Have a good day.*
Bye.*
See yeah.*
Later.*
Later days.*

--wrong output--
This is The last body.This is The last referral.Later.
```

Comment: Can you give some samples of your files? I think the problem is that when you're splitting the string, it's generating an empty string `""`. This happens often. An easy workaround is changing it to `sectionString = [word for word in file.read().replace("\n", "").split("*") if word != ""]`. See if this works.

Comment: I posted the wrong code before. It has been corrected.

Comment: A little tip- `string.strip("\n")` is a bit better than `string.replace("\n","")` in my opinion.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is a common problem in python. When you use `string.split(chars)`, python breaks the string using those characters even if there is nothing after the delimiter. So, for example, your 'intro.txt' would produce this list- `['Hi.', 'Hello.', 'Yo.', 'What up?', 'How are you?', '']`. This happens because there is one delimiter character at the end of the string. Python finds it, starts making a new list element from after it, but there's nothing, so, python leaves it as an empty string.

If you know the exact file contents then it's fairly easy to predict where the empty string will appear and you can manually remove them like, `sectionString = sectionString[:-1]`. But in most practical cases, you would only know the file format, not the exact content. In such case, the workaround I put in comment is the most reliable and easy way to clean up the empty strings and/or some other stuff as well if you want to.

So, change the splitting line to

```
sectionString = [word for word in file.split("*") if word != ""]
```

Edit: Even in case of multiple delimiters together like `"data1*data2**data3"`. Python would produce an empty string, just not at the end of the list but middle. So, the list would be like `["data1","data2","","data3"]`. And there can be multiple such empty strings. Happens all the times when I'm manually reading some csv files. Putting a conditional in list comprehension makes the result much more reliable.

Answer (score 0):

Because you end your final string with "*", when you do the split, you have a final empty item.

```
Python 3.8.10 (default, Nov 26 2021, 20:14:08) 
[GCC 9.3.0] on linux
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> a = "1*2*3*4*"
>>> a.split('*')
['1', '2', '3', '4', '']
>>>
```

You might consider `sectionString.rstrip('*').split('*')`, but in that case, why not just use `splitlines`?

Comment: In OP's case your solution is great. But in some cases, e.g., csv files, there can be multiple delimiters in the middle of the string. Something like, `"data1,data2,,,data3,`. In such case `string.rstip(",")` would fail. Such cases would require manually removing all empty strings.

Comment: It is inaccurate to say "rstrip would fail" unless you know what the requirements are.  In this case, his problem was an additional entry at end of file.  Perhaps he wants to keep blank words in the middle.  You're making an assumption.